# regex to remove prefix and another to uppercase the first letter

Tags: regex, perl

I need to do things in 2 steps here:

1. modify all occurrences of [xx_someText] with [someText]
2. modify all occurrences of [someText] with [SomeText]

I need this in 2 regexes because some table names are not prefixed with `xx_`.

I am on a Microsoft machine.

I have access to Unix, BUT I am using the GIT bash utility which seems to have sed and perl installed in case that is easer?

**UPDATE**

Sample Input:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xx_attribute](
 [attributeID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [dateTypeID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,

should output as:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Attribute](
 [AttributeID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [DateTypeID] [tinyint] NOT NULL

note: the values [int] and [tinyint] will prolly become [Int] and [Tinyint] which is no biggie.

Comment: Interesting that one can amass over 3.000 rep without having answered a single question...

Comment: Asking good questions can be as valuable as providing answers.  That's certainly consistent with my experience in charge of a classroom, though the situation is a bit different.

Comment: @Carl: That's definitely true.  And when you've asked 397 questions, some of them are bound to be good ones.

Comment: i do have a good question badge :)

Comment: You forgot to show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -pe "s/\[(xx_)?(\w+)\]/'[' . ($1 ? $2 : ucfirst $2) . ']'/ge"
```

Double quotes are used here because my understanding is that the OP is on the Windows command line.

Comment: Thank you for remind me about '-p'. I'm not used to one liners.

Comment: Good answer, but the xx_ may not be present so that should be: perl -pe 's/(?:xx_)?(\w+)/ucfirst $1/ge'.  Also note the single quotes, as you don't want the shell interpolating the $1.

Comment: The square brackets are part of the match also

Answer (score 3):

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
    s/\[(?:xx_)?([^]]+)\]/\[\u$1\]/g;
    print;
}
```

Of course, you can do it from the command line:

```
 perl -pe 's/\[(?:xx_)?([^]]+)\]/\[\u$1\]/g'
```

This was tested with your example.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xx_SomeAttribute]( [someAttributeID] [int] NOT NULL, [dateTypeID] [tinyint] NOT NULL
CREATE TABLE [Dbo].[SomeAttribute]( [SomeAttributeID] [Int] NOT NULL, [DateTypeID] [Tinyint] NOT NULL
```

Please note that **all** text inside brackets is affected.

Comment: hmm..didn't work, it returned: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xx_SomeAttribute](
 [someAttributeID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [dateTypeID] [tinyint] NOT NULL

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote, but did a  perl -ne '' < input.sql > output.sql

Comment: Oh, you should update your question then. You want to include the square brackets?

Comment: not sure I follow, my question has both the input and output text with the square brackets e.g. [SomeText] in #2 thanks!

Comment: did you try it using the 1 liner? hmm...mine not working using GIT bash in win7.

Comment: I did: perl -pe 's/\[(?:xx_)?([^]]+)\]/\[\u$1\]/g' < input.sql > output.sql and didn't work? very strange!

Comment: I used single quotes because my shell doesn't like the '$' sign

Comment: Then don't try to use the command line version -- use a script instead.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you can do:

```
sed 's/xx_\(\w\+\)/\1/' filename
```

Second part:

```
sed 's/\w\+/\u\0/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk makes this a one step thingy:

```
awk '{sub("^xx_", ""); print toupper(substr($0, 1, 1)) substr($0, 2);}'
```

Put your items on a single line. The sub() takes away the prefix, then the print statement prints the first remaining character in uppercase, the rest as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This works using GNU sed 4.2.1

```
sed 's/\[xx_/[/g; s/\[./\U&/g'
```

Comment: lol, that converted things to: [ b e  a l l s p a c e d o u t ]

Answer (score 0):

using just the shell

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr
while read -r -a arr
do
    for((i=0;i<=${#arr};i++))                    
    do
        case "${arr[i]}" in
            *"[xx_"* );;&
            *"["*)
                arr[i]=${arr[i]//xx_/}
                arr[i]=${arr[i]^^${arr[i]:1:1}}
        esac
    done
    echo ${arr[@]}
done < "file"
```

Comment: yes, so? if OP has it, then its fine. If not, there are other solutions around.

Comment: *Yes, so?* is a little glib, given that (1) you never mention that your answer requires a very specific version of Bash and (2) the vast majority of systems do not yet have that version available.

Comment: strange, a lot of us never mention Perl, or Python, sed or whatever software versions either, until later maybe. so what's the real problem here? some of you can be so pedantic. WTH